# Read contact with data extension from shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to create and read a contact in a shared mailbox using the Microsoft Graph API. So far, I managed to create a contact with an extension like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<SMB-ID>/contacts
"extensions":[
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
        "extensionName": "specialdata",
        "key1": "yes"
    }]

Response:
{
  ...
  "extensions": [
  {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "id": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.specialdata",
    "key1": "yes"
  }
  ]
}
```

My problem is that I can read the contact without extension but not with it via GET. Both ways described in the [docs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/opentypeextension_get) don't work.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<SMB-ID>/contacts?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'specialdata')
Response:
{
 "error": {
 "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
 "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
 "innerError": {
     "request-id": "441d4fd6-52a5-460a-a972-cddcd87222ee",
     "date": "2017-02-08T14:40:48"
     }
 }
}
```

The scope of my Bearer Token looks like this:

```
"scp":
"
Calendars.Read.Shared
Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
Contacts.Read.Shared
Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared
full_access_as_user
Mail.Read.Shared
Mail.ReadWrite.Shared
Mail.Send.Shared
User.Read"
```

Am I missing a permission in Graph, the shared mailbox or is it an unsupported feature?

Answer (score 1):

Your GET URL looks wrong. From that you're trying to list everything under the user entity. Since this is a contact, try:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<SMB-ID>/contacts?$expand=extensions($filter=id eq 'specialdata')
```

Comment: Hi Jason, your right, and I fixed the question. I used the correct URL but copy pasted the wrong one into the question.

Comment: Ah ok. I see this too when trying to query a shared mailbox. I can't post to extensions on an existing contact either. Let me do some digging.

Comment: Thx! I just want to give some context to avoid a solution for a wrong use case: 
My goal is to share mail, contacts and calendar for 2-5 users. All of them need to be tagged or extended which is the reason I'am looking into data extensions. 
If this sounds fine, please keep on digging :-)

Comment: Hi @jason, did you find out why it currently doesn't work?